# How can I work on PLSQL procedures with LOOP?

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL, so I would ask you for your help.
Currently, I will deal with one database by using PL/SQL.

Here is a data below, which will be processed.

[image]

This is where I cannot have idea to conduct below steps:

1. This procedure will generate an SQL sentence (e.g. SELECT * from DB WHERE ・・・)
2. Records gotten by the SQL will be assigned to another variable(Cursor in PL/SQL).
3. But the gotten records surpass 3,000 rows, The generated SQL will stop getting them after the 3,000 rows are assigned to the variable(Cursor)
4. After the Step 3 occurres, we edit the SQL sentence so that the records from the 3,001st onward would be selected when we conduct the Step 1 to Step 3 again.

Is it possible to loop procedures the way we want to loop? If yes, could you tell me how to write the code?
Now, it is so vague, but I can imagine these below codes:

```
create or replace procedure TEST1
IS
    strCondition := “WHERE ・・・ ORDER BY ~~~”
    strSQL := “SELECT * FROM DB” + strCondition;
    a NUMBER(3000) := 1;
BEGIN
    LOOP
    (Conduct the SQL to get records until it surpasses 3,000)
        IF a <3000 THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    a := a + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I would be extremely grateful if you could kindly show me the codes to deal with records every 3,000 rows

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should have described the **problem**, not the way you **think** it should be **solved**. Because, there might be a different / better way to do that, whatever you're trying to do.

For example, why do you want to generate `select` statement over and over again? I don't understand what you mean by saying that you'll assign those values to a cursor (*). And, what's the point doing it in chunks of 3000 rows?

---

Anyway, as the final question says

> is it possible to loop procedures the way we want to loop?

here's one option. I don't have your 100.000 rows table so I'll demonstrate it on Scott's `emp` table which contains 14 rows, so instead of 3.000 rows in a single round, I'll do only 3.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;  -- number of outer loop round
  3    l_str clob;    -- collect values returned in inner loop
  4  begin
  5    select ceil(count(*) / 3) into l_cnt from emp;
  6
  7    for i in 1 .. l_cnt loop
  8      for cur_r in (select ename, job
  9                    from (select ename, job,
 10                            row_number() Over (order by ename) rn
 11                          from emp
 12                         )
 13                    where rn > (i - 1) * 3
 14                    fetch first 3 rows only
 15                   )
 16      loop
 17        l_str := l_str || cur_r.ename ||'; '|| cur_r.job || chr(10);
 18      end loop;
 19      dbms_output.put_line('Round ' || i);
 20      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 21
 22      l_str := null;
 23    end loop;
 24  end;
 25  /
```

Result is then

```
Round 1
ADAMS; CLERK
ALLEN; SALESMAN
BLAKE; MANAGER

Round 2
CLARK; MANAGER
FORD; ANALYST
JAMES; CLERK

Round 3
JONES; MANAGER
KING; PRESIDENT
MARTIN; SALESMAN

Round 4
MILLER; CLERK
SCOTT; ANALYST
SMITH; CLERK

Round 5
TURNER; SALESMAN
WARD; SALESMAN


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, create a cursor and use `OFFSET x FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY` to paginate the cursor:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST1(
  i_page   IN  NUMBER := 1,
  o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cursor FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   db
    WHERE  something = 'true'
    ORDER BY column1
    OFFSET (i_page - 1) * 3000
    FETCH NEXT 3000 ROWS ONLY;
END;
/
```

When you want to get the 2nd (or higher) page of results then pass in the page number as a parameter to the procedure.